# How do I filter out "useful" mounts from /etc/mtab or /proc/mounts

Tags: files, mount, proc, user-interface

I'm currently writing a basic filesystem abstraction (in C++) and I need to get a list of "useful" mounted devices on linux.

I've found the function(s) `getmntent`/`getmntent_r` that allow to me to easily parse `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts` however many of the mounted devices aren't "useful" (such as: `/sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls`). In particular I'm attempting to find mounts which related to a physical device, partition or network share/drive.

The closest I've found is checking if the `mnt_fsname` (device name) starts with a `/`, which in the case of my system narrows it down to:

- `/`
- `/boot`
- `/run/media/[username]/0CA8-1F2D`
- `/run/media/[username]/14E0-3E80`

Which appears to be what I want (the latter two being partitions on a usb stick). I haven't had a chance to try out a network share/device with it though.

Basically this is meant to be an approximation of windows-like 'drives', hence why I'm interested in physical devices etc., but doesn't prevent a library user navigating to unlisted devices if they so-desire.

So basically the question boils down too:

- If the device name in a mount entry starts with a `/` is it guarenteed to be a physical device, partition or network share?
- Will I be leaving out anything particularly important/useful?
- Is there a better/more precise way to do this?

Comment: how about something akin to?:  df -x tmpfs -x devtmpfs

Comment: `/proc` is not a physical device, partition, or network share, so it is not guaranteed. Trying to implement windows 'drives' on linux sounds like a half-baked plan to begin with, since the linux way is a ton more flexible. Why exactly are you trying to do this?

Comment: @Wyatt8740 I can gather devices from multiple sources other than just /proc so that's a non-issue. I'm not so much as trying to implement windows 'drives' on linux, all I'm doing is providing 'system-agnostic' shortcuts to physical drives, paritions and network shares for ease of use. If the library user wants to navigate to a particular directory/device, they're not prevented from doing so.

Comment: @Theophrastus Actually that works beautifully. I'll need to figure out someway to use it a bit cleaner though, executing another program and parsing the output is a little clumbersome but not that big a problem - that and it adds another dependancy. But I'll see if I can wrap my head around the source.

Comment: Note that recent windows versions also permit mounting to directories.

Comment: @Wyatt8740 If windows assigns drive letters to them, I'll try and filter them out to make the library consistant. Since the library is intended for use primarily in games, in-depth information about the filesystem and mount points isn't particularly important provided that it's consistant.

Comment: @LivePastTheEnd ah. Games. that clears things up a bit. I'm gonna try to dig through the kernel API now, I'm getting interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a notion of “useful mounts” that makes sense in all scenarios. You want to include removable physical drives and network mounts, and exclude filesystems for system access such as those under `/dev`, `/proc` and `/sys`. What about filesystems mounted by the user? Knowing that a filesystem is provided by FUSE doesn't tell you what it is. It could be an archive, a network mount, an alternate view of a directory, a disk image, a way to control some program, …

Checking if the device name starts with `/` doesn't seem useful to me. For example it would include bind mounts and exclude network mounts.

I think the best you can do is to not reinvent the wheel. If nothing else, by using the same mechanism as others, you won't confuse your users (“why does X list that filesystem but not Y???”). Additionally there's a chance that what the others did might make sense.

So my recommendation is to use Gnome libraries, at least GTK+. GTK+ has a [file opening dialog](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) which shows some mounted filesystems under “Places”. Users can [control what is listed there](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gvfs/tree/monitor/udisks2/what-is-shown.txt) to some extent — [if they can figure it out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198996/prevent-the-gtk-file-dialog-from-listing-mount-points), that is. Even if you don't show the file open dialog from GTK+, use the same list of “places” (I don't know how to obtain that, look at the API documentation).

Comment: Actually that's pretty much perfect. Looking at the second link I believe I should be able to implement something that behaves identically and atleast while it's not a universal standard it's a flexible standard nonetheless!

Answer (score 0):

„useful“ my be a matter of opinion, but anyway, here is my take:

```js
  const getMount = (mountId, _parentID, _deviceNo, root, mountPoint, mountOptions, _fields, _mountSource, superOptions, blob) => (
    {
      mountId,
      // parentID,
      // deviceNo,
      root,
      mountPoint,
      mountOptions: mountOptions.split(','),
      // fields,
      // mountSource,
      superOptions: superOptions.split(','),
      blob
    })

  const mounts = fs.readFileSync('/proc/self/mountinfo', 'utf-8')
  mounts.split(/\n/)
    .filter(l => l.length > 0) // filter empty line at end
    .map((m) => getMount(...m.split(' ')))
    .filter((m) =>
      !/^\/(snap|run|sys|proc|dev)($|\/)/.test(m.mountPoint) &&
      !['mqueue', 'tmpfs'].includes(m.superOptions) &&
      !m.superOptions.includes('mqueue') &&
      !m.superOptions.includes('tmpfs') &&
      !m.mountOptions.includes('ro')
    )
    .map((l) =>
      console.log(l))
```

*(What I needed were devices, from where generally speaking files could be deleted and thus being relevant to a recycle bin path matters (how to calculate those is another matter))*